# How to SELECT two records for each unique column value as one row in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, greatest-n-per-group

I have a MySQL table like this :

```
+----+-----+-------+------+------+-------+---------------------+
| ID | GID | Name  |  p1  | p10  | p100  |      createdAt      |
+----+-----+-------+------+------+-------+---------------------+
|  1 | 100 | Item1 |  150 | 1499 | 10245 | 2020-07-04 12:00:00 |
|  2 | 857 | Item2 | 1047 | 9875 | 90000 | 2020-07-04 12:00:10 |
|  3 | 100 | Item1 |  149 | 1495 | 10245 | 2020-07-04 12:15:00 |
|  4 | 857 | Item2 | 1099 | 9875 | 89999 | 2020-07-04 12:15:10 |
|  5 | 100 | Item1 |  149 | 1495 | 10247 | 2020-07-04 12:30:00 |
|  6 | 857 | Item2 |  970 | 9879 | 89998 | 2020-07-04 12:30:10 |
+----+-----+-------+------+------+-------+---------------------+
```

What I try is to output for each unique `GID` value their `p1, p10, p100` of the two last most recent `createdAt`

Output example :

```
+-----+-------+------+------+-------+---------+----------+-----------+
| GID | Name  |  p1  | p10  | p100  | p1-last | p10-last | p100-last |
+-----+-------+------+------+-------+---------+----------+-----------+
| 100 | Item1 |  149 | 1495 | 10245 |     149 |     1495 |     10247 |
| 857 | Item2 | 1099 | 9875 | 89999 |     970 |     9879 |     89998 |
+-----+-------+------+------+-------+---------+----------+-----------+
```

I tried to use subqueries to achieve my goal but I am not confortable with that.

Thank you to anyone who can provide me informations and help.

Comment: What is your MySql version?

Comment: Hello, I am using mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 5.5.65-MariaDB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use `lag()` for this:

```
select gid, name, p1, p10, p100, prev_p1, prev_p10, prev_p100
from (select t.*,
             lag(p1) over (partition by gid order by createdAt) as prev_p1,
             lag(p10) over (partition by gid order by createdAt) as prev_p10,
             lag(p100) over (partition by gid order by createdAt) as prev_p100,
             row_number() over (partition by gid order by createdAt desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=8f462d09f72ac39502c2a2e537ed268a) is a db<>fiddle.

The subquery returns the previous values for each column.  The outer query simply filters down to the most recent row for each `gid`/`name` combination.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. However, LAG() function in MariaDB appeared at version 10.2.2. My MariaDB version is 5.5.65-MariaDB MariaDB Server.

Comment: I updated the MariaDB server to 10.4, the query returns "NULL" results for prev_p1, prev_p10, prev_p100.

Comment: Needed to change ``WHERE seqnum = 1`` to 2. (Thanks @forpas)

Comment: @Dampen59 . . . .It should be `where seqnum = 1`.  The issue is the `desc` order by in the `lag()`.  Oops.  I removed that.

Answer (score 1):

It's not easy and elegant without window functions.
This is one way to do it, which involves self joins, 2 levels of aggregation and conditional aggregation:

```
select t.gid, t.name,
  max(case when c.counter = 1 then t.p1 end) p1,
  max(case when c.counter = 1 then t.p10 end) p10,
  max(case when c.counter = 1 then t.p100 end) p100,
  max(case when c.counter = 0 then t.p1 end) p1_last,
  max(case when c.counter = 0 then t.p10 end) p10_last,
  max(case when c.counter = 0 then t.p100 end) p100_last
from tablename t inner join (
  select t1.gid, t1.createdat, count(t2.createdat) counter
  from tablename t1 left join tablename t2
  on t2.gid = t1.gid and t1.createdat < t2.createdat 
  group by t1.gid, t1.createdat
  having count(t2.createdat) <= 1
) c on c.gid = t.gid and c.createdat = t.createdat
group by t.gid, t.name
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7bWw9nthS5bBPHBL3taPNn/1).
Results:

```
| gid | name  | p1   | p10  | p100  | p1_last | p10_last | p100_last |
| --- | ----- | ---- | ---- | ----- | ------- | -------- | --------- |
| 100 | Item1 | 149  | 1495 | 10245 | 149     | 1495     | 10247     |
| 857 | Item2 | 1099 | 9875 | 89999 | 970     | 9879     | 89998     |
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. I tried your query but it seems that it takes a very long time on a populated table. I let the query run for more than 5 minutes and it was still running. Thank you foor your contribution anyway ! I've updated my server version of MariaDB to check Gordon's answer but it seems that it's not working. I am trying to fix it.

Comment: This is why you need window functions.

Comment: Yes, I have edited my comment. My MariaDB version was updated to 10.4

Comment: Change Gordon's answer to: `where seqnum = 2`